fileExists(atPath:) always returns false, but Data(contentsOf:) returns true for the same URL
I know these files exist because I selected them from a SwiftUI .fileImporter dialog. I even made sure to call .startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() and . stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() appropriately.
What boggles my mind is that this works as expected, just fine, every time:
Data(contentsOf: url)

but this returns false every time:
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path())

Even more bizarre, if I select a directory, this returns its contents as expected!
FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

What's going on here?

This tripped me up for a good couple hours until I discovered that .path(), despite seeming to be the designated replacement for the now-deprecated .path, doesn't behave the same.
.path() percent-encodes the URL before returning its path. To get the old behavior, you have to pass it false like this:
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path(percentEncoded: false))

This should work as you expect
